# Meta: Make [tagging] a synonym of [tags]

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, we have (on Meta) the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) tag with 1 follower and 14 questions. We also have the [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) tag with 0 followers, 2 questions.

These are just two ways of describing exactly the same topic.

I would therefore propose making [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) (like it is on [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tags/synonyms)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, nice catch.

[tag](/questions/tagged/tag)